# Pandas pulling wrong column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv that is structured like:

```
_________________________
|foo  | bar |     |     |
|     |need |bleep|bloop|
|     |this |bleep|bloop|
```

I am trying to pull out the values from the 'bar' column but all I get is 'bloop'.

Here is how I am trying to pull 'need':

```
df = pd.read_csv('PATH\TO\FILE')
value = df.iloc[1]['bar']
print(value)

>bloop
```

I cannot figure out why I just getting 'bloop' instead of 'need'. I have also tried using:

```
df.iloc[:,1]
```

to get the second column but nothing doing.

Edit: Here is the format of the first few csv lines, had to change due to sensitive info.

```
foo,bar
,need,bleep,bloop
,need,"some stuff, and, more, other, blah stuff, stuff",bloop
,need,"pretty, much, the, same stuff",bloop
```

Comment: Can you please post the first few lines of the actual .csv (open it in a text editor and copy). Otherwise it's difficult to reproduce the `.read_csv`.

Comment: @ALollz I have added the format of the first few lines

Comment: Have you tried printing `df.head()`? This is not at all the format that you're suggesting from how you've described the CSV structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the header row does not have enough fields. Because of this, `pandas`, assumes that the first two columns are an index, and gives you two columns `foo` and `bar`, which allows it to parse the file properly and avoid this kind of error:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None)
```

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line
>   2, saw 4

Since it's sometimes a pain to change the underlying data, just skip the first line and set the column names manulaly.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', skiprows=1)
df.columns=['foo', 'bar', 0, 1]
```

#### Output:

```
   foo   bar                                                0       1
0  NaN  need  some stuff, and, more, other, blah stuff, stuff   bloop
1  NaN  need                    pretty, much, the, same stuff  bloop
```

Comment: This is a better, more maintainable solution than what I proposed.

Comment: @PMende it all depends. Sometimes it's good to just fix the problem at the source and then the code will be much cleaner. Plus with a lot of columns, it's far easier to add two commas than it is to write out 75 column names.

Comment: Fair point. I suppose I assumed quite a bit about the use-case. :)

Comment: @ALollz nailed it! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Open your CSV file. Change the header from:

```
foo,bar
```

to:

```
foo,bar,,
```

Then rerun your code.